# Returning values from a vector type memory in openCL?

Tags: opencl

I am trying to use vectors in my OpenCL code. Prior to this, I was mapping the memory to and fro as

```
cmDevSrc= clCreateBuffer(cxGPUContext,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,sizeof(cl_char) * (row_info->width) * bpp,NULL,&ciErr);
cmDevDest=clCreateBuffer(cxGPUContext,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,sizeof(cl_char) * (row_info->width) * bpp,NULL,&ciErr);
```

I am using `cmDevSrc` as my source array of `unsigned chars` and `cmdDevDest` as for destination.
When I am trying to implement the same using vectors, I am passing the kernel argument as

```
clSetKernelArg(ckKernel,1,sizeof(cl_uchar4 )*row_info->rowbytes*bpp,&cmDevDest);
```

with  `cmDevDest` being `cl_uchar4 cmDevDest`.
But now, I cannot read back my data using mapping , with the following error,

```
incompatible type for argument 2 of ‘clEnqueueMapBuffer’ 
/usr/include/CL/cl.h:1066: note: expected ‘cl_mem’ but argument is of type ‘cl_uchar4’
```

I don't know any other method for this compile time error at this time and I am searching net but any help will very helpful.

Thanks
Piyush

Comment: Is the kernel argument in question a `cl_uchar4` or a `__global cl_uchar4*`? If the former, then you shouldn't be using `clCreateBuffer`. `clCreateBuffer` returns a `cl_mem`, which is why you are getting that compiler error.

Comment: this is the declaration 
`cl_uchar4 cmDevDest;`
and I am setting it as 
`clSetKernelArg(ckKernel,1,sizeof(cl_uchar4)*row_info->rowbytes*bpp,&cmDevDest); `
I dont how to allocate memory for a vector and pass is in kernels.Please do correct me ..

Comment: What is the declaration in the kernel source code?

Comment: @jprice
`__global uchar4 *out`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `clCreateBuffer` function returns a `cl_mem` object, not a `cl_uchar4` (or anything else), so `cmDevSrc` and `cmDevDest` should be declared as `cl_mem` variables. This is also what is causing the compiler error for your call to `clEnqueueMapBuffer`.

Additionally, the `arg_size` argument of `clSetKernelArg` should be `sizeof(cl_mem)` when you are passing memory object arguments, not the size of the buffer:

```
clSetKernelArg(ckKernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &cmDevDest);
```

Comment: U r correct, but i want to use vectors in kernel, so I hv to pass something that can hold  vectors, so I am passing the way I said.
Now its working fine but I dont know how to read back from a `uchar` and thats what the problem is...

Comment: @PiyushKumar A `cl_mem` can hold vectors - it's just a chunk of memory that doesn't have any type attached. How you use it inside your kernel is up to you, and interpreting it as an array of vector types is fine. Regardless of how you use it inside your kernel, you *always* pass it to `clSetKernelArg` in the manner that I show above (with `sizeof(cl_mem)`).

Comment: @PiyushKumar You can read back the data in exactly the same way that you would for non-vector types, using `clEnqueueReadBuffer` or `clEnqueueMapBuffer`. If you have a specific problem with this please update your question with the details and I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: thanks. It worked ....Also if u can tell me whether I could use any static variable inside the kernel or not